# shrinking a Docker Image - from debian to scratch - how to migrate?

Tags: dockerfile, debian-buster

i am trying to build a minimalistic `docker image` for one of my applicatoins

in my "usual" builds i do not rely on 3rd party applications. This time I need to include a precompiled executeable (xpdf) to the build; My `go` applications are prebuilt in a `builder` Docker and then copied over (no dependencies).

my current `Dockerimage` file looks like this: (working!) application launches

```
FROM debian:buster-slim
COPY ./bin64/pdftopng .
COPY ./config/xpdfrc .
# ... copy FONT files
# copy Test PDF
COPY ./test.pdf .
RUN chmod +x pdftopng
RUN apt-get update && apt-get install -y libfontconfig1
# execute pdftopng
ENTRYPOINT ["/pdftopng", "-cfg", "xpdfrc", "/test.pdf", "/test.pdf"]
```

as this results in a image file with over 100mb i tried to use `scratch` as a base (which usually results in images around 10-20mb)

```
FROM scratch
# ... copy my binaries to the docker
COPY --from=builder /dist/main /
# copy the XPDF -> pdf to png executeable (linux x64)
COPY ./bin64/pdftopng .
# copy font files (for this example i only copy one)
COPY ./fonts/n021003l.pfb /fonts/n021003l.pfb
# copy config file
COPY ./config/xpdfrc .
# copy test file
COPY ./test.pdf .
# execute the XPDF converter and convert the test.pdf to png
ENTRYPOINT ["/pdftopng", "-cfg", "xpdfrc", "/test.pdf", "test"]
```

outputs:

```
standard_init_linux.go:219: exec user process caused: no such file or directory
```

this error is the result of a missing library (something related to libfontconfig1)
how can i find out which files are missing (as i do have a working container this should be possible)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

### Solution

### Step 1 - create libsource

create a docker image where you can grab all required libraries from

```
FROM debian:buster-slim AS libsource
COPY ./bin64/pdftopng .
COPY ./config/xpdfrc .
# ... copy FONT files
# copy Test PDF
COPY ./test.pdf .
RUN chmod +x pdftopng
RUN apt-get update && apt-get install -y libfontconfig1
```

### Step 2 - find requirements

then obtain a list of libraries which the application [./pdftopng] needs to run

```
docker run --rm -it ldd ./pdftopng
```

this command lists all required libraries (direct use only):

```
    linux-vdso.so.1 (0x00007ffce1304000)
    libbz2.so.1 => /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libbz2.so.1 (0x00007fa1104ea000)
    libz.so.1 => /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libz.so.1 (0x00007fa1102cc000)
    libfontconfig.so.1 => /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libfontconfig.so.1 (0x00007fa110286000)
    libpthread.so.0 => /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libpthread.so.0 (0x00007fa110265000)
    libstdc++.so.6 => /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libstdc++.so.6 (0x00007fa1100e1000)
    libm.so.6 => /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libm.so.6 (0x00007fa10ff5e000)
    libgcc_s.so.1 => /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libgcc_s.so.1 (0x00007fa10ff42000)
    libc.so.6 => /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libc.so.6 (0x00007fa10fd81000)
    libfreetype.so.6 => /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libfreetype.so.6 (0x00007fa10fcc5000)
    libexpat.so.1 => /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libexpat.so.1 (0x00007fa10fc88000)
    libuuid.so.1 => /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libuuid.so.1 (0x00007fa10fc7f000)
    /lib64/ld-linux-x86-64.so.2 (0x00007fa110501000)
    libpng16.so.16 => /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libpng16.so.16 (0x00007fa10fc44000)
```

### Step 3 - copy requirements

in the last step copy the libraries from step 2 to the `scratch` image

```
COPY --from=libsource /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libbz2.so.1 /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libbz2.so.1
COPY --from=libsource /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libz.so.1 /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libz.so.1
COPY --from=libsource /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libfontconfig.so.1 /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libfontconfig.so.1
COPY --from=libsource /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libpthread.so.0 /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libpthread.so.0
COPY --from=libsource /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libstdc++.so.6 /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libstdc++.so.6
COPY --from=libsource /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libm.so.6 /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libm.so.6
COPY --from=libsource /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libgcc_s.so.1  /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libgcc_s.so.1
COPY --from=libsource /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libc.so.6 /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libc.so.6
COPY --from=libsource /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libfreetype.so.6 /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libfreetype.so.6
COPY --from=libsource /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libexpat.so.1 /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libexpat.so.1
COPY --from=libsource /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libuuid.so.1 /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libuuid.so.1
COPY --from=libsource /lib64/ld-linux-x86-64.so.2 /lib64/ld-linux-x86-64.so.2
COPY --from=libsource /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libpng16.so.16 /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libpng16.so.16
```

### Result

in my case the result is a much smaller image `15.45 MB` instead of `101.90 MB`

which is a reduction by `84,84 %`